# Im trying to modify some images in a folder in python for training my ML image recognition program

Tags: python, keras

```
 File "R:\envs\tutorial\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

This is the line that stops the program. I tried searching for a solution on the forums and all I could find is that my interpreter and my OS are not compatible but when I searched both of them were on the x64 version which in theory was the problem.

This is the code

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, array_to_img, img_to_array, load_img


Y = "drives"


sample_Y_image="R:\train\Y1.jpg"



datagen=ImageDataGenerator(
                           rotation_range=40,
                           width_shift_range=0.2,
                           height_shift_range=0.2,
                           rescale= 1.0/255,
                           shear_range=0.2,
                           zoom_range=0.2,
                           horizontal_flip= True,
                           fill_mode='nearest')

img= load_img(sample_Y_image)

x = img_to_array(img)
x = x.reshape((1,) + x.shape)

i = 0

for batch in datagen.flow(x,batch_size=1,save_to_dir='R:\preview',save_prefix=Y,save_format='jpeg'):
    i += 1
    if i> 90:
        break
```

Any ideas what could cause the problem?

Comment: Show the code please

Comment: First time using this platform, added the code for clarity

Comment: Quick guess: when you use backslashes in strings, you must use raw strings, e.g., `r"c:\test\path"` so that the `\t` doesn't get turned into a tab.

Comment: that doesn't seem to be it